# Find condition on $A$ and $B$ so that $|q_o|+|q_1|<1$.

Tags: inequality

I have to find condition on $A$ and $B$ so that
$$|q_o|+|q_1|<1$$
Where 
$$q_0=\frac{-1-4A+C+(2B+1)\sqrt{8A+(B+C-1)^2}-B(2B+2C+1)}{8A-4(B+C)}$$ 
and
$$q_1=\frac{-1-4A+B+(2C+1)\sqrt{8A+(B+C-1)^2}-C(2B+2C+1)}{8A-4(B+C)}$$
Where $A,B,C$ are positive real numbers.

**The required condition is $B>2A$**.They say that if $B>2A$ then $|q_o|+|q_1|<1$

I try to find this but i failed.